# How to unhide node in Houdini?

Tags: houdini

I hidded my node with context menu

[image]

Now how to get it back?

I found [this strange tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Z-wRufeYs), suggesting to use `Textport` and showing something incredible.

Is it possible to unhide nodes with the same simplicity as I faced hiding them?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the tree view, you can still see your hidden node, and from there you can toggle *hide flag.*

Answer (score 0):

Version 16.5 of Houdini has solved this problem.

In the new version, clicking again hides the node as well as unhide.

It is now a toggle - Hide/Unhide node.